# Open all files within Start Date & End Date.

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to open all files within a folder that belong in a date range.

This is what I used so far: This opens all of the files within a folder. But even though I placed a "Marker" so I don't open the files I don't need, I need a more advanced technique...

```
        Dim sFname As String

        Dim MyFiles() As String
        MyFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, "*_x" & "*.xlsx", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)


        For Each sFname In myFiles

        'And the code to open the files in excel.
```

I started with this: DateTimePicker1.Value as starting date, Picker2 as ending date.

```
    Dim STDate As String
    STDate = DateTimePicker1.Value

    Dim EnDate As String
    EnDate = DateTimePicker2.Value
```

I searched for hours, but haven't found anything useful...

Please help.

Comment: You will need to explain what you mean by "belong in a date range". Do you mean files that were last updates in a date in some date range? The Value property of DateTimePicker returns a DateTime and not a string, so STDate and EnDate should probably be of type DateTime rather than String. That would make it easier to test if a given date is between STDate and EnDate.

Comment: By belong in a date range -> Example: A folder contains 10 files. The first file was created on 1st this month. The last on 10th this month. I want to open the files within that folder, filtered by the pick a start date, and pick an end date. So, if I select 2th this month, to 5th this month in datetimepicker, I only want to open the files that were created from 2th to 5th.

Comment: Check out the [`FileInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
For Each filePath In Directory.GetFiles("*.xlsx").
                               Where(Function(s) File.GetCreationTime(s) >= startTime AndAlso
                                                 File.GetCreationTime(s) <= endTime)
    'Use filePath here.
Next
```

or

```
For Each info In New DirectoryInfo(folderPath).GetFiles("*.xlsx").
                                               Where(Function(fi) fi.CreationTime >= startTime AndAlso
                                                                  fi.CreationTime <= endTime)
    Dim filePath = info.FullName

    'Use filePath here.
Next
```

Comment: What is `FolderPath` and `FilePath` ?  I tried something similar to this, but I couldn't get the files to open. I assume `FolderPath` is the location where the files are. Then, what do I do with `FilePath`? "'Use filePath here." Thanks for helping out.

Comment: This is the reason why when I tried something similar before it didn't work. ">=" I assume this means if its equal or bigger than the starting date? But lets say for example, I select 1th this month as starting date, and 10th this month as ending date. All the files in-between will open, but the files that were created on "1th & 10th" won't open.

Comment: So this means I need to set the timepicker to have the hour at 00:00. And not take the current hour. Ok, problem solved. Thanks.